Casimir element vs Hamiltonian
Consider, for example, the phase space of a free particle moving in $\mathbb R^3$. The Euclidean Group acts on the phase space preserving the canonical symplectic form and the kinetic energy. To the Lie algebra of this group we can associate a second order Casimir element, "momentum squared". It will act as a second order differential operator on the phase space. On the other hand, the symplectic gradient of the momentum squared function will be a vector field, a first order differential operator. Is there a connection between the two? A general theorem?
From the way physicists talk about it, it seems that there is a connection after quantization. Is that step necessary?
